# How can I change listening port of SSDT from localhost to interface IP of my machine

Tags: powerbi, sql-server-data-tools

I would like to ask if its possible to change listening port of Integrated Workspace Database server to be able to listen on interface of my machine so remote users can connect. I have Visual Studio 2017 - SSDT installed and Integrate Workspace listening on localhost:*some port*

I can connect to the port via PowerBI running on my local machine. I would like to enable it also for remote user.

I tried:

- port forwarding, it is displayed in CMD proxy output but does not work
- firewall is OFF
- No other proxy or anything else is on the computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my further analysis you cannot change the port or set it to specific port, it always connects to the random free port. However what you can do is to use Port Forwarding on your machine

e.g. like this

`netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=3340 listenaddress=10.1.1.110 connectport=3389 connectaddress=127.0.0.1` - because it also listens on this loopback address